# How to store the client_secret in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, signature

I have an API which I will call from an android app. The authentication is with oauth2 and I have the `ressource owner password`-flow. 
So when I want to get an accesstoken I need username, password, clientId and clientSecret.

My problem is: How can I store the clientSecret in my app? I read that someone stores it in bytes an generates the string when he needs it.
My idea was to use the signature(SHA) as clientSecret. 
So I found this function:

```
private String getKeyHash(String packagename)
{
    String hash = "";
    try
    {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packagename,     PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String sign= Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sign,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {

    }
    return hash;
}
```

Which is the better/safest solution?
Or is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you store it in `SharedPreferences` or db? Only your app can access to them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect the data from? If it is malicious apps then SharedPreferences as anil is suggesting is the default option. If it is against reverse engineering nothing you do in the app will help you.

Comment: I want to identify my app. Only my app is allowed to use the API. So when you ask from what I protect the data. Then the answer is reverse engineering. When I use the signature as secret, nobody can get the secret, only if he has the signature, didn't he?